# How to install Beagle on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu

I've been trying to install Beagle on my 11.04 installation of Ubuntu.

The Beagle site says that Beagle is shipped with Ubuntu.  But from the software center in Ubuntu, a search for Beagle returns zero results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beagle was shipped with ubuntu. It no longer is. Think 10.04 was the last ubuntu release in which it was shipped(Not very sure).

I suggest you use tracker along with cardapio. I am using the same currently and so far so good. I was previously using beagle.

Else you can always build beagle from source(Beagle is no longer developed though).

Answer (score 1):

You can try and give the Lucid Lynx (10.04) package a try, I guess that'll be the only option right now since it wasn't available for 10.10 either.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/beagle